# PulseAudio - Speakers crackling in ubuntu minimal install

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio

I have installed Ubuntu minimal. My speakers setup is 5.1. When I use FFplay to play a clip, I get a crackling sound. The sound is working perfectly in a full Ubuntu desktop install. But when in Minimal, I installed alsa and pulse audio, I get the crackling sound.

Is there any difference in sound architecture between Desktop and minimal versions

Ubuntu Version 16.04